# Advantages/Disadvantages of indexing per element or by integer

Tags: python, python-3.x, indexing

For some reason I seem to struggle a lot when the exercises given uses a lot of indexing  (such as matrix multiplication, or accessing data from a list inside a list inside ....

I can't tell when iterating over x,

```
for i in x:
    print(i)
```

is better/worse, than indexing by integer,

```
i = 0
while i < len(x)
    print(x[i])
    i += 1
```

Can someone please highlight the advantages/disadvantages of both?

Comment: The first code you showed isn't "indexing per element", not sure what you mean by that. That is simply iterating over `x`. It isn't clear to me what you are asking. The second example **makes no sense**. You are using the values in `x` to index into `x`. Why the `while` loop? Can you give an actual, concrete example of where you would use that second piece of code?

Comment: Python generally encourages you not to use indices unless you really need to. As such, the first example is generally preferred. If I saw the second example in a code review I would assume you didn't have much experience with Python.

Comment: sorry i messed up a bit, i edited it

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I fixed it, I messed up.

Comment: I wanna point out that the "indexing by integer" is more commonly performed with a `for` loop, not a `while` loop: `for i in range(len(x)): ...do something with x[i]...`

Comment: @KevinWang ah yeah idk why i wrote a while loop there

Answer (score 0):

It seems like they're about the same speed: [What is faster for loop using enumerate or for loop using xrange in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852944/what-is-faster-for-loop-using-enumerate-or-for-loop-using-xrange-in-python)

However, you can do both by enumerating:

```
for index, value in enumerate(my_list):
    # do stuff...
```

Answer (score 0):

`for i in x:` on both examples do the same thing. I think your examples are not what you mean to ask.

```
for i in x:
  print(i)
```

vs

```
for i in range(len(x)):
  print(x[i])
```

do the same thing. It iterates over the elements. Other than typing additional square brackets, I do not see any advantages on using one over the other.